# Issue Adding custom product attribute with UI Select - Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, uicomponents

I created a custom product select attribute using below setup script and trying to make it UI-Select, underneath code to set "location" attribute as UI-Select but in admin 2 select options are getting appear. Once as default select and 2nd one is with UI-Select for same attribute.

I tried to check Internal implementation like over CMS pages and other places but unable to figure-out why the attribute showing twice. I am looking for UI-Select due to huge number of data and aiming to use lazy load which I already figured-out to achieve.

Here is create attribute code:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'location',
        [
            'group' => 'General',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Location',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'VendorName\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\Location',
            'required' => true,
            'sort_order' => 50,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    );
}
```

product.xml over path VendorName/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="product-details">
        <field name="location">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">VendorName\Module\Model\Attribute\Source\Location</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Location</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="searchUrl" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please let me know if I am missing any step..

Comment: Have you found a solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

check \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav

Comment: Can you please elaborate what should be checked and what should be found?